# Neo4j Recursive Query with relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, tree, cypher, hierarchy

If I'm managing a family tree in a neo4j graph database, I want to run a query that will retrieve a person and all of their descendants. I run the following:

```
MATCH
            (ancestor:Person {name: '<persons name>'}) -
            [:ParentChild*1..] ->    (desc:Person)
        RETURN 
            [ancestor, desc]
```

This gives me the ancestor and all of their descendants, but the relationships are lost. How do I also capture the relationships so that later I can iterate over the list and find a parent or children of any individual in the list?

I come from a relational background where normally store the parent_id in a person and just return that with each person object.

Comment: Check the nodes() and relationships() functions for working with paths in the cypher manual https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-nodes

Answer (score 0):

You just return sets of pair of 'parent/relationship/child' as an array of maps.

```
MATCH(ancestor:Person {name:<persons name>})-[:ParentChild*1..]->(desc:Person)
WITH collect(distinct id(desc)) as ids
MATCH (ancestor:Person)-[r:ParentChild]->(desc:Person)
WHERE id(desc) in ids
RETURN {ancestor:ancestor, relationship:r, desc:desc} order by ancestor.name
```

Comment: How come you MATCH the parent child relationship twice? Is that faster than returning everything from the first MATCH? @norihide.shimatani

Comment: The first one is for collecting ids of nodes on a path. (A)
The second one is for pairing parent/child nodes on a path(A).
And RETURNs parent/child sets. @Will Harrison